# Reading from excel with OleDbDataAdapter some numeric cells coming in scientific notation?

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

Reading from excel with OleDbDataAdapter some numeric cells coming in scientific notation. Only the strings that are only numbers (some may contain letters) and are six or 7 digits or more. It is not possible for me to put a ' before each cell. In newer versions of excel there is no problem at all. Problem comes with older versions (I think it's 2003 but I'm not certain)

```
Dim dt As DataTable = dbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, _
                                     New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

Dim dbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "]  ", dbConn)
```

I've tried everything, I don't know what to do. I've tried selecting each column by name and concatenating an empty string, I've tried adding IMEX=1 to the connection string. or modifying the registry:

```
    Private Function CheckRegKey() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim strRows As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue( _
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel", "TypeGuessRows", "99").ToString
        Dim strTypes As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue( _
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel", "ImportMixedTypes", "zip").ToString

        If strRows <> "0" Then
            My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel", "TypeGuessRows", 0, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        End If
        If strTypes <> "Text" Then
            My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel", "ImportMixedTypes", "Text")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function

Dim dbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & strSheet & "]  ", dbConn)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the excle column format to text. This treats the entry as a string.

Comment: Or you can try increasing the width of the column.

Comment: Like within the excel program? It already is.

Comment: The width in the excel program? I'm not sure what property that is, but there are values in that column with letters mixed with numbers that are much longer than the scientific notation ones and they are unaffected

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to be able to fix it by modifying the select statement. This works when used in conjunction with the code I had above.

I only included the column that was giving me problems, but because I switched it from SELECT * to specifying column data it is important to include each column name you need.

```
Dim dbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT FORMAT(part_no, ""######"") As part_no FROM [" & strSheet & "]  ", dbConn)
```